# Jetson tx2 to Teensy 3.6 Serial communication issue

Tags: microcontroller, serial, communication

I am trying to establish serial communication between Nvidia Jetson Tx2 and Teensy 3.6. Using *pyserial*, while reading the data sent from Teensy 3.6 on Rx pin on the Jetson, I come to an error that shows "device reports readiness to read but returned no data" after 3-4 seconds. Before that, it works fine (it is unreliable).

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to rectify it?

Thank you

Comment: `Does anyone know ...?` ... probably the person that wrote the python script knows ..... what event causes the message to be displayed?

Comment: Post your related code to communication, what have you tried, and error message